# Fix Position of ThreeJS Model While Scrolling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using ThreeJS and GSAP and I am trying to keep my 3D model fixed to the background, and rotate the mesh while scrolling. Here is the code I am using: https://jsfiddle.net/n2qw9rg8/3/

I have a div with id `3d` and I am using `document.getElementById('3d').appendChild(renderer.domElement);` to add the model to that div. Then I styled the 3d div with `position: fixed` but the div refuses to fix to the background. What am I doing wrong?

I want the sections to scroll on top of the rotating model.

Comment: It's invalid to have an ID (or class name) start with a number. Use a letter instead and it works.

Comment: That fixed it! Starting the ID with a letter fixes it. Thank you.